# Copy all files from one location to another in Linux, without copying the directory itself

Tags: linux

I want to copy some or all files from a directory `test/A/` to directory `test/B/`, but without copying directory A itself.

I tried the command `cp -R test/A/ test/B`, but it copies the directory and the files as well and become `test/B/A/`…

Answer (score 3):

When you specify `test/A/`, you tell Bash to copy the directory itself.

To copy only the contents of a directory, use [the `*` glob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob):

```
cp -R test/A/* test/B
```

Here, `*` will match all files in A, except hidden ones prefixed with a dot, e.g. `.htaccess`. To include these as well with a `*`, call `shopt -s dotglob` before.

Answer (score 1):

to get an identical copy locally or remote I would prefer `rsync` over `cp`. This gives you much finer control over what should be copied or even deleted either on source or destination if so desired. And by the way fixes issues with hidden files (aka `.*`). Basic usage is as simple as with `cp` though.

to copy a directory `A` and it's contents to `B` use:

```
rsync -va test/A test/B
```

to copy the contents of directory `A` (including hidden files) to `B` use:

```
rsync -va test/A/ test/B
```

if B does not exist it's created